# Check if user is already logged in Parse - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse to signup a user and login. I have completed those modules successfully. Now my doubt is that, where and how do I check if the user is already logged in. If the user is already logged in, show him the MainActivity else show him the HomeActivity.

Currently I have the HomeActivity as my launcher in the `Manifest`

```
<activity
          android:name=".Activities.Home"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Then I have a Application class where I initialise the parse object.

```
   public class MyClass extends Application {
    public static Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        Parse.initialize(this, "KEYS", "KEYS");

        if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().isAuthenticated()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Home.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting this error in the logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.artqueen.aahaan.Aahaan: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.parse.ParseUser.isAuthenticated()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5255)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1536)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.parse.ParseUser.isAuthenticated()' on a null object reference
            at com.artqueen.aahaan.Aahaan.onCreate(Aahaan.java:33)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1536)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

How do I achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just go through the code and I bet you will understand the logic to create this [Check Out This](http://androidexample.com/Android_Session_Management_Using_SharedPreferences_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=127&aaid=147)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Parse docs:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
  // do stuff with the user
} else {
  // show the signup or login screen
}
```

Did you try this?

Answer (score 2):

try this tutorial complete example using parse login and Signup..
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-simple-login-and-signup-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to call `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().isAuthenticated()` in application.

Check this...
Official parse login example app
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

ParseUI contains user interface libraries for building apps with the Parse Android SDK.

```
 public class SampleApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Required - Initialize the Parse SDK
    Parse.initialize(this);

    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);

    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

    // Optional - If you don't want to allow Twitter login, you can
    // remove this line (and other related ParseTwitterUtils calls)
    ParseTwitterUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key),
        getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declear Applicaton class in manifest class first then try your code.

Comment: Define application class in your Manifest class above activity.